# UiPath Sending Exceptions to Azure Application Insights

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception, azure-application-insights, uipath

Trying to create an exception handler that will update Azure Application Insights when hit.
I've tried two different types of Invoke Codes but neither are appearing in Application Insights.

I have no experience in using Azure Application Insights so I'm hoping that I am either missing a permission to be set or something is missing from the code.

"in_key" refers to the Instrumentation Key

C# Attempt

```
// Create a new instance of TelemetryConfiguration
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration configuration = Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

// Set the instrumentation key for your Azure Insights instance
configuration.InstrumentationKey = in_key;

// Create a new instance of TelemetryClient with the configuration
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient(configuration);

//Send Exception
telemetryClient.TrackException(in_exception);
```

VB.Net Attempt

```
Dim telemetryClient As New Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient
telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = in_key
Dim exceptionTelemetry As New Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.ExceptionTelemetry(in_exception)
exceptionTelemetry.Properties.Add("AdditionalProperty1", "Value1")
exceptionTelemetry.Properties.Add("AdditionalProperty2", "Value2")
telemetryClient.TrackException(exceptionTelemetry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to above, we found adding a Flush was allowing the exception to get to Application Insights.

```
 // Create a new instance of TelemetryConfiguration
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration configuration = Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

// Set the instrumentation key for your Azure Insights instance
configuration.InstrumentationKey = in_key;

// Create a new instance of TelemetryClient with the configuration
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient(configuration);

//Send Exception
telemetryClient.TrackException(in_exception);
telemetryClient.Flush();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```